# How jQuery can show array of objects like console.log() of Eclipse

Tags: jquery, json, textarea, console.log, stringify

I'm printing an array of objects using jquery. I want to print them inside a textarea, every row an object. For example console.log() of Eclispe print so:

```
{eventID: 1, time: "2017-08-23 10:01:34", level: "INFO", message: "[loadDB]}

{eventID: 2, time: "2017-08-23 10:01:35", level: "INFO", message: "[chargeDB]}
```

Instead using jquery:

```
$('textarea#textLog').text(JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 2));
```

I got these:

```
[
  {
    "eventID": 1,
    "time": "2017-08-23 10:01:34",
    "level": "INFO",
    "message": "[loadDB]"
  },
  {
    "eventID": 2,
    "time": "2017-08-23 10:01:35",
    "level": "INFO",
    "message": "[chargeDB]" 
  }
]
```

How i can use jquery to print an array of object inside a textarea like the console.log() I showed before ?

Comment: I don't know if there's any specific debug command, but you could just use a simple for loop, iterate through your array and append the current value of the index to the textarea.

Comment: I'm a beginner. In this manner it show me only the last object. I need to show all objects of the array in the same time. All the list

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/bvc8sy31/1/

Comment: Cool !!! thank you ! You solved it. Grazie

Comment: You ever going to pick a correct answer, OP? ;)

Comment: I answered by the comment above

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this if you want to do it with jQuery:

```
var objectArr= [
  {
    "eventID": 1,
    "time": "2017-08-23 10:01:34",
    "level": "INFO",
    "message": "[loadDB]"
  },
  {
    "eventID": 2,
    "time": "2017-08-23 10:01:35",
    "level": "INFO",
    "message": "[chargeDB]" 
  }
]

$.each(objectArr, function(index, val) {
    console.log(val.category);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your JSON object, you forgot a quote, therefor JSON.stringify cannot parse it. Just add quotes at the end of the "message" value like so :

```
message : "[chargeDB]"}
```

[Working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wqgn2Lau/1/)

Comment: Sorry there are the quote, it was a problem of paste and copy. I edited